# Is there a symbol to indicate a fraction normalized to the unit interval [0 to 1]?

Tags: terminology, fractions

I'm looking for a symbol/character that quickly conveys to the reader that the number that follows is to be understood as a decimal fraction in the range from 0 (minimum) to 1 (maximum). So for example "humidity: 0.4<symbol>" would represent the same idea as "humidity: 40%".

This would be analogous to the % (per cent) and ‰ (per mille) signs. When you read a table column labeled as "% humidity" or "% unemployment" you understand well and immediately that the numbers that follow below are relative to the range 0 to 100.

I want to use this in in table headers, function annotations, on UI buttons, as boilerplate text, and so forth. I.e. anywhere where there isn't a lot of space and it's better to be succinct. It would appear alongside other shorthands such as Σ for sum, ⌀ for average, Δ for difference, # for ordinal, etc.

For now I'm using the unit interval notation [0, 1] or [0...1] as a prefix or postfix but it's not always well understood.

I should mention that I'm unable to modify the data itself, so I can't just change 0.4 to 40% and use the percentage symbol instead.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but isn't that what the decimal point indicates?

Comment: OK, I get it. In a logarithm, for example, it would be the mantissa. For a table header, perhaps something like $0.x$ would do.

Comment: The very fact you have to ask should indicate that there is no widely recognized symbol, so you'd need to explain anything you used. Something of an abomination, but you could use $$\frac {\%}{100}$$